# MVC 4 SimpleMembershipProvider using SQL Server without EntityFramework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Is it possible to set up MVC 4 with SimpleMembershipProvider without EntityFramework, or do I need to write a custom provider?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You may try it by creating a new application from "*Internet application*" template, then delete everything which belongs to EF. Then create *Users* table by yourself and edit the conection string and the call of `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()`.
The *Users* table will be populated automatically when you call `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()` without EF at all.